# pandas: filter rows using more than one column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am filter out some rows of a data frame based on values of a given column like below:

```
new_df = my_df.loc[my_df['A_count'] == 0.0]
```

The code works fine. Then I tried to filter out rows using values from two columns like below:

```
new_df = my_df.loc[my_df['A_count'] == 0.0 & my_df['B_count'] == 0.0 ]
```

Then the code gave me error:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

How do I actually perform the filter using the values more than one column? Thanks!

Comment: You need parenthesis around each condition.

Comment: works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @root pointed out... this works

```
new_df = my_df.loc[(my_df['A_count'] == 0.0) & (my_df['B_count'] == 0.0)]
```

---

However, you could also use `query`
I like `query` because it automatically filters for you and the query syntax is often very intuitive.  Notice the lack of parenthesis.

```
my_df.query('A_count == 0 & B_count == 0')
```

Comment: Very much appreciate seeing an example of `query` in action!